# Check to see if a specific DAG is present or not in Composer using Cloud Shell?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-shell

I am trying to use a Cloud Shell command to check if a specific DAG is present or not (if it exists), but I am unsure what command to write in order to accomplish this.

For example, if I wanted to check to see if `my_dag.py` exists, I would like Cloud Shell to indicate whether it is present or not.

So far, I have used this command, but it lists all of the DAGS:

```
gcloud composer environments storage dags list --environment=ENVIRONMENT --location=LOCATION
```

I want to specifically check to see if a certain DAG exists or not using Cloud Shell, but I do not know how what command to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`airflow dags list`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#list_repeat2) command (which is what this Cloud Shell command is using) has a `--subdir` option where you can specify the file path to a DAG file. The output will be the DAGs tied to that fileloc.

```bash
gcloud composer environments storage dags list --environment=ENVIRONMENT --location=LOCATION --subdir dags/path/to/file.py
```